# Highcharts pie charts individual sections are not receive focus. Tooltips are not displayed on focus

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have several pie charts with few sections, for example this one:

- [Pie chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk0y8.png)
- [With hover on section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeRmb.png)
- [With focus on section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsZvR.png)
- [Pie chart sandbox demo with custom function that adds tabindex](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-herschel-9dgf9)

But there is few issues with it: it doesn't receive any focus when i'm trying to reach any of sections with "Tab" button, and, if i add tabindex="0" in devTools manually tooltip doesn't displayed on focus, is there any way to fix it (both of this issues with focus and tooltip)?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue on some online editor with the sample data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thank you for the advice, added sandbox example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - I encourage to use the official Highcharts react wrapper which is fully supported by Highcharts - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

To navigate the chart by keyboard you need to attach the `accessibility module` - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8jL40mvb/

Comment: Well, it's doesn't work as i expected, but it's at least something, thank you!